# Twitter API OAuth can't get access token

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I just got this porblem that suddenly stopped working, I'm using Twitter API in my node and does the OAuth login flow, it's been working since i started this project, it just strangely stopped working today, the lost below shows what I tried that all failed:

1. what I read on twitter's developer site the limit is 15calls per 15min for every user, i waited 15mins before login again, not working
2. created new app, change consumerkey and consumerSecret, not working
3. tried on another twitter account, not working
4. tried on another IP, not working

Error message when I try to trace the error:

`Error getting OAuth access token : { statusCode: 401, data: ' ' }[undefined][und
efined][undefined] 500`

But when I run my other project with twitter login that uses same app, share same IP and same code as this project, it surprisingly worked.

So why just this project not working, I'm running out of idea. If anyone has experienced same issue please share! Thanks.